# mvn test fails, but mvn test -e pass all tests

Tags: junit, maven-3

I am running maven test goal in IntelliJIDEA with a set of JUnit tests. If I execute a goal in maven tab by clicking the goal one test fails.

```
>mvn test -e
Tests run: 74, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

If I double click maven test (surefire plugin) I get

```
 Tests run: 74, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

What could cause this behavior?